# How do I toggle states after every timeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on injecting words from an array into an element using `setTimeout`. I'm also using [Baffle.js](https://github.com/noahlemen/baffle-react) to add an obfuscation transition to said word change.

The flow should be something like:

word 1 -> obfuscate over 3s -> word 2... and so on.

My code is below:

```
render() {

        return (
            <div className='landing-page-wrapper'>
                <div className="main-text">
                    <span>AMIDST </span>
                    <Baffle
                        characters={'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz~!@#$%^&*()-+=[]{}|;:,./<>?'}
                        exclude={[' ']}
                        speed={50}
                        revealDuration={0}
                        obfuscate={this.state.obfuscate}>
                        {this.state.targetWord}
                    </Baffle>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


    toggleObfuscate() {
        this.setState({ obfuscate: !this.state.obfuscate })
    }

    injectWords() {
        const wordslist = [
            'creativity', 'emotion', 'logic', 'change', 'positivity', 'direction', 'thought', 'humanity'
        ]

        wordslist.forEach((words, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({targetWord: words})
            }, (index+1) * 3000)
        })
    }
```

---

I've managed to inject the words over 3 seconds, however, I can't seem to get the obfuscation part down. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't understand, in wich way the targetWord state should trigger something with the obfuscate state ?

Comment: From the github doc it looks like the component needs a update attribute tied to the state, have you tried to set `update="this.state.update"` ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit the obfuscate should happen for every targetword. Though, I'm not sure how to get that going.

Comment: @savageGoat the `update` prop basically stops the continuous transitioning, but doesn't stop the obfuscation part.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 15.03.2022

I managed to fix this issue by adding a `setTimeout` to the `toggleObfuscate()` function. This basically resets the state value for `obfuscate`

The fix looks something like this:

```
toggleObfuscate() {
        this.setState({ obfuscate: !this.state.obfuscate })

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({obfuscate: false})
        }, 1000)
    }

    injectWords() {
        const wordslist = [
            'creativity', 'emotion', 'logic', 'change', 'positivity', 'direction', 'thought', 'humanity'
        ]

        wordslist.forEach((words, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({targetWord: words})
                this.toggleObfuscate();
            }, (index+1) * 3000)
        })
    }
```